# How to create a list template with modified view/edit/disp.aspx

Tags: custom-list

I need to create about 40 identical lists that the editform.aspx has been modified to add certain web parts (for example script editor).

a) Is this possible?

b) If it's not, is here a workaround? One is to add the javascript to the master page and then the javascript will decide whether or not to run, depending on the page.

Comment: Option A sucks if you ever need to make (small) changes. Option B gives you loads more control, then also look into UserCustomActions

Comment: The javascript will add business logic, like making readonly fields, checking fields, etc.

Comment: So you want one library, also checkout SPs native CSR (Client Side Rendering) options, and use the WYSIWYG Cisar Chrome Extensions

Comment: CSR depends on javascript, so I need to have script editor in list template

Comment: CSR is attached with a JSLink, it doesn't need a SEWP, UserCustomActions are global in the SiteCollection, so even better